# "AMD Unsupported Hardware" watermark in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I just setup my new computer that has onboard video and Installed Linux Mint. I installed the "ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" from Hardware Drivers and now I have a watermark on the bottom left of my screen that says "AMD Unsupported Hardware".

Why is this there? Is there anyway to get rid of this?

**Onboard video specs:**
ATI Radeon HD 4200 GPU
SidePort Memory - onboard 128MB DDR3 1333 memory

**@Jared Harley:** I've been searching around and havn't found a fix for this. /etc/ati/control exists so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer!

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Found my hardware under Linux x86_64 > Integrated/Motherboard > Radeon HD 4200

"Linux x86" means 32 bit
"Linux x86_64 means 64 bit

Download the driver somewhere (lets put it in '~/stuff')
Open up the terminal and type:

```
user@user-desktop:~/stuff $ cd ~/stuff
user@user-desktop:~/stuff $ chmod +x NAMEOFTHEFILEHERE.run
user@user-desktop:~/stuff $ ./NAMEOFTHEFILEHERE.run
```

And the driver will be installed.

Answer (score 3):

According to a post at [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NTkyMg):

> With the fglrx 8.39.4 driver (or
>   newer), there's a chance you may run
>   into a watermark (similar to the [AMD
>   testing watermark](http://www.phoronix.com/?page=news_item&px=NTkwNg)) saying that
>   your hardware is unsupported when in
>   fact it is supported. If you run into
>   this unsupported hardware watermark,
>   it's likely that /etc/ati/control is
>   missing. If that's the case for you,
>   try reinstalling the driver or
>   manually copying the control file. The
>   driver contents can be extracted using
>   the --extract argument and the control
>   file is located in common/etc/ati/. If
>   you experience this problem, create a
>   thread in the Phoronix Forums with
>   what distribution you are using and
>   how you had installed the driver
>   initially (and whether adding the
>   control file had removed the
>   watermark).

Other people also had luck downgrading their video driver to one version lower.

Answer (score 1):

I have an ATI HD 6520 in my Acer Ao 522.  I had to upgrade to the latest driver (in my case 12-6 64bit) to get multi-displays to work.

I tried [what James suggested](https://superuser.com/a/108217/48078) and it didn't work for me. Though the driver seems to chug along with the replaced file. The watermark goes away when I open up Catalyst.

I may give the open source driver another shot next time I have time to fool with it.  I heard ATI has better support with the open source driver than NVIDIA, though on my other machine with a Quattro card, NVIDIA drivers work great.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to unpack the drivers

```
./ati-driver-installer-10-1-x86.x86_64.run --extract
```

I then copied the new file into the old place

```
cp /etc/ati/control /etc/ati/control-old
cp common/etc/ati/control /etc/ati/control
```

It got rid of the watermark for me and the old proprietary driver appears to still work with the new control file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the open-source "ati" driver instead of fglrx. The performance will be abysmal but you won't have the watermark (no one is going to code such an anti-feature in a FLOSS driver).